# Javascript date function with current date

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following script.

```
   <script>
   $(function() {
   var date = $('#date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
   });
   </script>
```

It displays the datepicker when selected the text box. But I want the current date as default in the text box.Help me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 1)using php you can to it easily as:
        <input type="text" id="date" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d')?>" />


2)by using datepicker you can do it like below:

var date = $('#date').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
}).datepicker('setDate', new Date()).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using jQuery UI's datepicker, you can use [`setDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) to set the date.

```js
var date = $('#date').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
}).datepicker('setDate', new Date()).val();
```